# What is the problem in sellToken function? Transaction reverts whenever i call that function

Tags: solidity

This is my solidity

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: none
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

interface ERC20 {
    function totalSupply() external view returns (uint256);
    function balanceOf(address account) external view returns (uint256);
    function transfer(address recipient, uint256 amount) external returns (bool);
    function allowance(address owner, address spender) external view returns (uint256);
    function approve(address spender, uint256 amount) external returns (bool);
    function transferFrom(address sender, address recipient, uint256 amount) external returns (bool);
    event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint256 amount);
    event Approval(address indexed owner, address indexed spender, uint256 amount);
}

contract BuyAndSell {
    
    address public owner = msg.sender;
    address private contractAddr = address(this);
    // address payable private comissionAddr = payable(0x2cA90f6BE87cd46E9cF68Eb6DFD94825fa257956);
    uint buyPrice = 15;
    
    function buyToken(address _tokenAddress,address payable comissionAddr) public payable returns (bool success) {
        ERC20 token = ERC20(_tokenAddress);
        uint tokens = msg.value * buyPrice;
        require(token.balanceOf(contractAddr) >= tokens);
        uint comission = tokens * 5 / 100;
        token.transfer(comissionAddr, comission);
        tokens  = tokens - comission;
        token.transfer(msg.sender, tokens);
        return true;
    }
    
    function sellToken(address _tokenAddress, uint tokenAmount) public returns (bool success) {
        ERC20 token = ERC20(_tokenAddress);
        require(token.balanceOf(msg.sender) >= tokenAmount);
        uint allowance = token.allowance(msg.sender, contractAddr);
        require(allowance >= tokenAmount);
        token.transferFrom(msg.sender, contractAddr, tokenAmount);
        return true;
    }
    
    function withdrawERC20Token(address _tokenAddress, address _to, uint _amount) public returns (bool success) {
        require(owner == msg.sender);
        return ERC20(_tokenAddress).transfer(_to, _amount);
        
    }
    
    function withdrawETH(address payable _to, uint _amount) public returns (bool) {
        require(owner == msg.sender);
        _to.transfer(_amount);
        return true;
    }
    
    receive() external payable{}
}
```

Comment: Hello. How do you call your function ? What is the exact error you get ?

Comment: @FlorianCastelain I verified this on rinkeby etherscan. From there I am using it. I can buy tokens but when i sell, metamask shows transaction error. Error thrown in contract code

Answer (score 0):

```
function sellToken(address _tokenAddress, uint tokenAmount) public returns (bool success) {
    ERC20 token = ERC20(_tokenAddress);
    require(token.balanceOf(msg.sender) >= tokenAmount);
    uint allowance = token.allowance(msg.sender, contractAddr);
    require(allowance >= tokenAmount);
    token.transferFrom(msg.sender, contractAddr, tokenAmount);
    return true;
}
```

In this function, the contract asks

1. if a user has enough balance
2. if the contract can spend enough coin on behalf of the caller

then it executes the transfer.

In particular, `allowance`

> returns the remaining number of tokens that spender will be allowed to spend on behalf of owner through transferFrom. This is zero by default.

However, to modify this value you need to first call `approve`

`approve(address spender, uint256 amount) → bool`

> Sets amount as the allowance of spender over the caller’s tokens.
> Returns a boolean value indicating whether the operation succeeded.

Comment: Thankyou for the answer. I removed allowance and added the approve function just after declaring the token instance. But still the same error

Comment: The approve function is part of the ERC20 standard. You should call the one exposed by your referenced ERC20 contract.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I had to approve the spender from the original token contract address.